# Why am I getting a syntax error (python number checking function)?

Tags: python

I've written this function in Python, which is designed to check if any list element is a number, and return that list element if it is. This is the code:

```
def check_for_number(list):
x = 0
print(isinstance(list[x], (int, float))
true_or_false = False
for x in range(len(list)-1):
    if isinstance(list[x], (int, float) == True):
        true_or_false = True
        num = list[x]
    x += 1
print(true_or_false)
return true_or_false 
return num
```

Whenever I try to run it I get a syntax error saying that the colon at the end of the if statement is an 'unexpected token', and every item in the last two lines of the if statement gives the same unexpected token error. I've checked the indentation and I can't see anything wrong with it, what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: `== True` is unnecessary. Get rid of it.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the end of the first print

Comment: Also, you can't return after you've already returned, so you'll only get back `true_or_false`, which really should have a more descriptive name

Comment: @JosephYoung Thanks, but even with that print statement completely removed I'm still getting the same syntax errors.

Comment: @cricket_007 why is == True unnecessary? I thought that might be the case that a function can only return one value, thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Youve essentially written `if True == True`. Its redundant, thats all. `if ininstance(...):` is all you need there. And you didnt close a parenthesis anyway

Comment: Some other things,  dont name a variable `list`. Thats a builtin function you overwrote. You do not need `x` as a number. You  can loop over `for e in lst:` to loop over all elements

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the tips, I've made some improvements using them. The issue now is that the function is still returning False even when the list contains a number, and I can't figure out why!

Comment: `x += 1` will skip values in your current code

Comment: @cricket_007 Why? Wouldn't it increment the index of the list element by 1 each time?

Comment: Yes, but the for loop already does that on its own

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah right, I see. So if I didn't use the range function and just had for x in list, it would increment through each element of the list anyway?

Comment: Correct. Loops over elements instead of indices, so instead of `list[x]`, you'd only use `x`

Comment: @cricket_007 Ahh that is a much more efficient way of doing it! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to indend the code of your function and fix the `if isinstance(list[x], (int, float) == True):` part and close the paranthesis of your first print statement.

```
def check_for_number(list):
    x = 0
    print(isinstance(list[x], (int, float)))
    true_or_false = False
    for x in range(len(list)-1):
        if isinstance(list[x], (int, float)) == True:
            true_or_false = True
            num = list[x]
        x += 1
    print(true_or_false)

    # Decide what you want to return here
    return true_or_false 
    return num
```

If you are interested in improving your code, remove the `== True` part, as has been stated in the comments as well. And from your question I assume you want to return fals, if `true_or_false` is `False` or `num` otherwise.

If you add a `break`statement in the loop, the loop will be exited when you have found the first number. So your computer does not need to loop through the complete list and this can save you some execution time.

I also expect, your `x += 1` statement is not what you want to do. The `for ... in range ...` loop will increase your x in each cycle. That is why `x += 1` will make your code skip every second list element. You also will not need to declare x first.

```
def check_for_number(list):
    print(isinstance(list[x], (int, float)))
    true_or_false = False
    for x in range(len(list)-1):
        if isinstance(list[x], (int, float)):
            true_or_false = True
            num = list[x]
            break
    print(true_or_false)

    if (true_or_false):
        return num
    else:
        return False
```

---

*Concering your question about the unnecessary `== True` part:*

The if statement is working like the following pseudo code.

```
if (CONDITION) == True then do something special
```

So, if you add a `== True`, python would check it like so:

```
if (valeu == True) == True then do something special
```

which is the same as:

```
if (value) == True then do something special
```

Comment: `== True` is not conform to [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), instead use `is True` or just nothing!

Comment: Thanks so much! The tips on optimising it are much appreciated. I am curious as to why == True can be omitted though? As I thought the if statement wouldn't execute otherwise. Cheers!

Comment: the if statement will check a condition, if it is True or False. If the condition is True, the code in the block after the if will be executed. Otherwise the execution will continue after that block. For more clarification, please see my next answer update.

Comment: `if (true_or_false): return num` seems verbose ... Just `return num`

Comment: @user2154065 Thankyou so much! Your explanation was really helpful, I also appreciate you pointing out the use of the x += 1 statement. You're right, that wasn't what I wanted to do haha. Cheers for the great advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a list comprehension.  It checks each element against the `Number` abstract base class.  It will return a list of numbers, since there might be more than 1 numeric elelement.

```
import numbers

def get_numbers(l):
    return [x for x in l if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
```

example:

```
>>> l = ['1', 4.0, 'abc', 'XYZ', 'test', 5]
>>> nums = get_numbers(l)
>>> print(nums)
[4.0, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is part of the code I'm working on for a task I've been set, and one of the rules for the task is that you can't use external libraries. Would the python standard libraries be excluded from this rule? I'm wondering if I can import modules like numbers?

Comment: I would assume so... since the standard library is not an external (3rd party) library.

Comment: @IH96 This is [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html),  nothing is external here

Comment: Also, this is probably the better solution because it's all numbers, not just the first one that's found

Answer (score 0):

Python is tab-sensitive and intolerant of errors in this regard. I'm also seeing an instance of an unmatched parenthesis on line 6. Try the following and you might get a more informative error on what to fix next:

```
def check_for_number(list): 
    x = 0 
    print(isinstance(list[x], (int, float))
    true_or_false = False 
    for x in range(len(list)-1):
        if isinstance(list[x], (int, float) == True): # missing a parenthesis to close isinstance. 
        # "== True" is unnecessary because isinstance() will resolve to True or False
            true_or_false = True 
            num = list[x]
            x += 1 
            print(true_or_false) 
            return true_or_false 
    return num # this will result in unexpected behavior...
        # ...because num will not be defined if this line is reached.
        # Either the return inside the if will finish the method or num will never be defined.
```

It's a bit ambiguous how some of that should be indented because I can't tell what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to return to values, consider returning a list or a dictionary containing the values.

Comment: Probably should not `x += 1` within a range loop unless you want to skip elements